# publish an installation of hadoop in the local maven repository

Tags: maven, jar, hadoop, customization

I am using an AMI image that has hadoop 0.20.205.1 pre-installed and configured.

Now, I have a project which search for this hadoop dependency in maven.

How can I publish the hadoop jars which are in /usr/share/hadoop to my local m2 repository?

Comment: The image has pre-installed parts of Hadoop which is not the same as being in the Maven repository. So you have to create an installation package from the dependencies via maven-assembly-plugin, rpm-maven-plugin etc.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems I want the opposite: install a local hadoop installation in the maven repository.

Comment: But this will not change the way how to get to the target. You need to install the local one instead of the Maven repository.

Comment: Yes, exactly. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have simple jars you can call mvn install:install-file with [appropriate parameters](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html).

Comment: Indeed, it seems like this will do. Here is an example: http://jeff.langcode.com/archives/27